# How to import markdown(.md) file in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, markdown

I am trying to import readme files in typescript but getting "error module not found"

My TS code

```
import * as readme from "./README.md"; // here i am getting error module not found
```

I also tried: typings.d.ts

```
declare module "*.md" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

I found that in typescript 2.0 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-20
 they have introduced "Wildcard character in module names" using that we can include any extension file.

I just followed example https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79 which is for json files I followed same for markdown files but no success.

I am not using webpack and any loader, so I just wanted it only from typescript

Comment: markdown is not json, you should probably load it using an actual http request.

Comment: I know markdown is not json. I just referred that solution and implemented for markdown files

Comment: @LokeshDaiya did you found any solution on this already?

Answer (score 37):

For those using React with Typescript:

Create a `globals.d.ts` file in your root directory *(e.g. `src/`)* with the following code:

```
declare module "*.md";
```

then import it like this:

```
import readme from "../README.md" // substitute this path with your README.md file path
```

Comment: This did it for me!

Comment: To be clear: 'root directory' refers to the `src` folder, not the directory above containing the `package.json`

Answer (score 19):

**Angular 8, TypeScript 3.5.2**

Create a file `globals.d.ts` in the **`src`** folder (has to be in `src` to work), add:

```js
declare module '*.md';
```

In your component or service import with:

```js
import * as pageMarkdown from 'raw-loader!./page.md';
```

In this case `page.md` was at the same level as the component I was importing it into. This worked with `serve` and `build --prod` also. Make sure to restart your `serve` if testing it in live reload mode for the first time.

There's a cleaner process for importing `json` - see the [TypeScript 2.9 Release Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule)

> Note: you don't have to name the file `globals.d.ts`, it could be called `anything-at-all.d.ts`, but that's the convention

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works the best for me, without the `raw-loader!`. I'm working with Nx, and the file had to be in /src folder, I wonder why tho?

Comment: Yes, Angular 8, but inside a library that i share with multiple apps

Comment: I'm in Angular 13. This works to a point. I get an error: Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'raw-loader'.

Comment: Raw loader has never been officially supported on Angular, and no longer works accidentally See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/21582. In 2022, if you want to statically import anything thats not html/ts/css you need to add a preprocessing step that wraps it in a json file, and then import that json file.

Comment: Yes, you can import JSON, because resolveJsonModule is just a tsc option so webpack doesn't know about it. Thats why I said you need to first wrap markdown in a json file. But you can't use webpack's raw-loader because angular 13+ doesn't configure webpack that way.

Answer (score 4):

In your linked example, they are importing JSON, not Markdown.  They are able to import the JSON because valid JSON is also valid JavaScript/TypeScript.  Markdown is not valid TypeScript and so importing it like that just isn't going to work out of the box like that.

If you want to access the Markdown file at runtime, then make an AJAX request to retrieve its contents.  If you *really* want it built within your JavaScript itself, then you will need to have some sort of build script.  You mentioned you aren't using Webpack, but it will be able to achieve what you're looking for by adding a module rule tying `/\.md$/` to `raw-loader`.  You'll need to use some sort of equivalent.

**Edit:**

It seems you learn something new every day.  As OP pointed out in comments, TypeScript 2.0 has support for importing non-code resources.

Try the following:

```
declare module "*!txt" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}

import readme from "./README.md!txt";
```

The `readme` value should then be a string containing the contents of README.md.

Comment: If you see in typescript changelog 2.0 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-20   they have introduced "Wildcard character in module names"

Comment: I stand completely corrected, after looking at that link @LokeshDaiya.  It does support non-code imports, you just have to specify the relevant content type and pattern in the module declaration.

Comment: I tried this solution but got this erro module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './README.md!txt'

Comment: It's working for me.  Are you still putting the `declare module` statement in your typings.d.ts file and the `import` statement in your regular *.ts code?

Comment: My typing.d.ts code `declare module "*!txt" {
        const value: any;
        export default value;
    }`   and TS file code is `import readme from "./README.md!txt";
console.log(readme);`

Comment: I have created a plnkr as well https://plnkr.co/edit/7qT4Tu?p=preview there also its not working

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with a new Angular CLI 8.2.0 project, TypeScript 3.5.2

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, nothing worked for me with this setup:
Vite + React + Typescript

## Step 1

What I ended up doing is creating a custom plugin in `vite.config.ts` to get the raw content from markdown files:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    {
      name: "markdown-loader",
      transform(code, id) {
        if (id.slice(-3) === ".md") {
          // For .md files, get the raw content
          return `export default ${JSON.stringify(code)};`;
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

## Step 2

Then I just tell typescript to import markdown files correctly in `vite-env.d.ts`

```
declare module "*.md";
```

Answer (score 1):

@Mitch's answer didn't work for me. Using angular v7, I found I could just use this syntax: `import * as documentation from 'raw-loader!./documentation.md';`

Answer (score 0):

For those using React with Typescript:

find file in `src/react-app-env.d.ts` file with the following code:

```
declare module "*.md";
```

then import it like this:

```
import readme from "../README.md" // substitute this path with your README.md
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Other's answers , I need to add a fetch request as well

So, overall steps are :

### Step 1 :  create a file markdown.d.ts with the code :

```
declare module '*.md' {
    const value: string; // markdown is just a string
    export default value;
}
```

### Step 2 : Add this code in your desired .tsx file

```
import data from '<path_to_md_file>.md'

useEffect(() => {
        fetch(data).then(res => res.text()).then(text => console.log(text))
}, [])
```