# How to import a markdown file in a typescript react-native project?

Tags: typescript, react-native, markdown

I have tried to import a markdown file into my typescript react-native project in 2 ways.

```
import * as readme from "./sample.md"
```

```
import readme from "./sample.md"
```

Both didn't work. So I found [a similar issue reported previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678315/how-to-import-markdown-md-file-in-typescript) and mentioned about making a typings.d.ts file for declaring modules, and i've tried this as well but it still doesn't work.

```
declare module "*!txt" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}

declare module "*.md" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

EDIT:
There is no import error on Vscode but on the react-native app itself, it says that it cannot find module './sample.md' as it is only looking for (.native|.ios|.json|.ts etc) files.

Any help would be appreciated, been stuck on this for far too long.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. Create one **type definition** (*index.d.ts*) file in one of the project directory and put the following code.

```
declare module "*.md";
```

2. Add `tsconfig.json -> CompilerOptions -> typeRoots` as following

```
{
     "compilerOptions": {
         ...
         "typeRoots": [ "<types-directory-created-in-#1>", "./node_modules/@types"],
         ...
     }
}
```

3. In your component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import readme from 'path/filename.md';

export default function ComponentName() {
    const [md, setMD] = useState("");

    //Use componentDidMount(): if class based component to load md file
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(readme)
            .then(data => data.text())
            .then(text => {               
                setMD(text);
            })
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>{md}</div>
    )
}
```