# How to load an .md file on build when using create-react-app and Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, markdown, create-react-app

I am trying to get load a markdown file to be loaded on build. I have setup a create-react-app that uses Typescript and using a [material_ui](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/blog) blog theme.

```
import ReactMarkdown from 'markdown-to-jsx';
import post1 from './blog-post.1.md';

export default function Main(props: MainProps) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { posts, title } = props;

  return (
    <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        {title}
      </Typography>
      <Divider />
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Markdown className={classes.markdown} key={post.substring(0, 40)}>
          {post}
        </Markdown>
      ))}
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

If a post is assigned to be markdown, it will render correctly: `const post = '# Sample blog post #### April 1, 2020 by [Olivier](/)'`

So the issue is that .md file is not loading into the variable.

When `npm start` is run, the html displays: `/static/media/blog-post.1.09e7833f.md`
Why would this be and what is that number: 09e7833f in the filepath?

I would ideally like to load the file in during build time so that it can be served more quickly on somewhere like Netlify. I do not want to use an asynchronous fetch like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42928796/10984558) answer suggests.

I assume I would have to create a webpack loader? The problem with this is that create-react-app has `webpack.config.js` in the `node_modules` which means customising it would be overwritten during a new build. I don't think using [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) helps if I can't configure it.

I've also tried `import post1 from 'raw-loader!./blog-post.1.md';` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57444766/10984558) but Typescript doesn't know what to do with that.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems to be something that's been asked previously (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3025), but unfortunately it doesn't seem possible right now to directly import markdown as a string in JavaScript/TypeScript.

When asking `create-react-app` to import an `md` file, it seems to get a URL (with a hex string) to the file instead of the raw string contained within. A workaround is as follows:

1. Create a `.d.ts` file to tell TypeScript how to interpret an `md` file:

```
declare module '*.md' {
  const value: string; // markdown is just a string
  export default value;
}
```

2. Import your `md` file (`the_text.md`) as follows

```
import theTextFile from './the_text.md';
```

3. `fetch` the contents of the file to get the actual markdown (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2961#issuecomment-322916352)

```
const [postMarkdown, setPostMarkdown] = useState('');

// useEffect with an empty dependency array (`[]`) runs only once
useEffect(() => {
  fetch(theTextFile)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((text) => {
      // Logs a string of Markdown content.
      // Now you could use e.g. <rexxars/react-markdown> to render it.
      // console.log(text);
      setPostMarkdown(text);
    });
}, []);
```

4. Place the markdown text into the Markdown tag and it will be rendered:

```
<Markdown className={classes.markdown}>
  {post}
</Markdown>
```

Keep in mind you can also override the JSX elements used to display the final thing. For Material-UI, this could look something like:

```
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { MarkdownToJSX } from 'markdown-to-jsx';

const Foo = (): JSX.Element => {

  const MdOverrideTypography = ({
    children,
  }: // ...props
  React.DetailedHTMLProps<
    React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>,
    HTMLParagraphElement
  >): JSX.Element => (
    <Typography paragraph>
      {children}
    </Typography>
  );

  const mdOverrides: MarkdownToJSX.Overrides = {
    // "p" paragraph elements are substituted with MUI "Typography"
    p: MdOverrideTypography,
  };

  // ...

  return (
    <Markdown options={{ overrides: mdOverrides }}>
      {post}
    </Markdown>
  )
}
```

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-to-jsx#optionsoverrides---rendering-arbitrary-react-components)

Comment: Does anyone know how material-ui is doing it on their sample site online? (https://material-ui.com/getting-started/templates/blog/)  Are they loading it during their SSR build?  Their code is structured similarly to the question above.  Thanks

Comment: Minor update you may want to consider: typography is now include via:

 import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

Answer (score 1):

An easy way seems to be to use the [raw.macro](https://github.com/pveyes/raw.macro#readme) package (I quote from the start of its README):

> **Installation**
>
> In order to use raw.macro in your own project, you can use one of the
> following commands:
>
> ```
> # or $ npm install --save-dev raw.macro
> ```
>
> Make sure babel-plugin-macros already installed. If you're using
> Create React App, it's installed by default.
>
> **Usage**
>
> raw.macro is similar to Node’s require call:
>
> ```
> import raw from "raw.macro";
>
> const markdown = raw("./README.md");
> ```

TypeScript sees the `markdown` variable as type `string`.

The one problem is that editing the markdown file doesn't cause the project to rebuild, to include the change. Instead you have to touch (e.g. re-save) the source file which imports it.

Comment: Yes - I can confirm that. It's a known issue https://github.com/pveyes/raw.macro/issues/20

For me that was the decisive factor to go with the `raw-loader` approach instead. Besides the caching issue, raw.macro works just fine.